# Show a viewController through another viewController, Swift

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have the result of my UISearchController in a separated UITableViewController (TableSearch).

I want, when we select a row, to show the DetailViewController with navBar and tabBar, and have the back button which lead to the SearchViewController.

I tried :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        var viewController = UIViewController()
        titreDetail = "Boo"
        viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! DetailViewController

       self.showViewController(viewController, sender: nil)
    })
```

But it present the DetailViewController without the navBar and the tabBar.

I tried this after :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        //SearchViewController
        var vc = UIViewController()
        vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Search") as! SearchViewController
        //DetailViewController
        var viewController = UIViewController()
        titreDetail = "Boo"
        viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Detail") as! DetailViewController

       vc.showViewController(viewController, sender: nil)
    })
```

Nothing happens..

How can I do it to have something like :

SearchTable -> SearchViewController -> DetailViewController ?

**Thank you!**

[image]

Comment: use `pushViewController` instead of `presentViewController`

Comment: I tried  vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true) and self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true). Nothing happens.. The SearchTable is not linked to a navigationController..

Comment: You will either have to pop the searchTable first, or create the navBar/tabBar again for the new ViewController, or push the searchTable too in order to inherit the navBar/tabBar

Comment: Okay, the tabBar is displayed on the SearchTable, and the UISearch outler is in the navBar. And my DetailViewController is not embed within a navigation controller.. And even if I recreate tabBar and navBar the view will  still pop.. ( I try to have the same result as in Instagram with their search view! )

Answer (score 0):

use 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

Comment: I tried  vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true) and self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true). Nothing happens.. The SearchTable is not linked to a navigationController..

Comment: you want to go from search view controller to search table and search table is not showing the navigation bar on the top ..Right ...?

Comment: When I am on the searchTable, I want to go to the DetailViewController, it shows the DetailViewController but on pop and the the navBar and the Tabbar are disappeared..

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
view controller is the instance you created of the view controller you want to push - L.Valentine

Answer (score 0):

Actually I created a Delegate protocol and it works perfectly..

```
  protocol SearchTableDelegateProtocol {
  func didTapExtendInSearchViewControllerWithIndex(hashtag: String,  inTrending: SearchTable)
}

class SearchTable : UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var delegate : SearchTableDelegateProtocol?
....

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("vc1")
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        self.delegate?.didTapExtendInSearchViewControllerWithIndex(self.filtered[indexPath.row][0], inTrending: self)

    })
}
```

Then :

```
class SearchViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, SearchTableDelegateProtocol {

var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchTable") as!  SearchTable
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

    locationSearchTable.delegate = self
 }

...


func didTapExtendInPhotoCollectionViewCellWithIndex(index: Int, inTrendingCell: CollectionCellOne) {
    print (index)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("hashtag", sender: "Instagram")

   }
 }
```

Thanks everyone!